# php header not forwarding ie9

Tags: php

I use the following which works perfectly in all browsers, except ie9

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT u_id, from users where (id = '$userID')",$db); 
$item = mysql_fetch_row($result);

$how_many = mysql_num_rows($result);

// if not a user send to reg
if ($how_many < 1){ 
header("Location: /pages/registration");
}
```

It simply does not forward - the header function does nothing - however, if i change the last block of the code to what is below, it works?!?!

```
if ($how_many < 1){ 
header("Location: /pages/registration");
// added echo for ie9
echo "<br /><br /><br /><br />here i am ";
}
```

I cannot fathom any logical reason for this, am I missing something?

Comment: are you sure there's no whitespace above? you removed that as well to do your successful check.

Comment: Any errors in your error log?

Comment: no and no to the above - whitespace would cause a PHP error (cannot send headers) of which there is none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't need to do any more processing after the redirect you should [exit](http://php.net/exit) after you send out the `Location` header:

```
if ($how_many < 1){ 
    header("Location: /pages/registration");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's certainly a way out. But I'd like to point that 'echo' command doesn't terminate the php process either, still with it header is processed correctly. Go figure. )

Answer (score 1):

By exiting or echoing, the buffers are flushed by the web browser, which IE9 awaits before taking action.

The following will also work:

```
header('Location: /page');
flush();
```

I would recommend exit/die to be used after the header function is called to prevent unnecessary code/resources being utilized.